# Card Height changes after data table row nos changes. but need to remain same

Tags: laravel

Good Evening... Refer image . I am facing problem about card height changes when datatable row nos are reduced compare to side card. I tried to used flex but no luck as height remain same but width of table get reduced.

[image]

Comment: You mean when you click pagination (1,2), your Milk Data card height changed depend on tables rows?

Comment: Yes... for 1st 5 row height is ok but when 2nd page open with 4 row, height reduced

Comment: inspect your wanted html element and change height with css